# React map data to tailwind grid

Tags: reactjs, css-grid, tailwind-css

I want to render the users who has property `eligible: true` to a grid using tailwind css

```
  const users = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      age: 23,
      pic: 'someUrl'
      eligible: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Marie',
      age: 6,
      pic: 'someUrl'
      eligible: false
    },
    {
      name: 'David',
      age: 30,
      pic: 'someUrl'
      eligible: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Sarah',
      age: 20,
      pic: 'someUrl'
      eligible: true
    }
  ]
```

---

```
     <ul className="grid grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-4 mt-4 px-10">
        {users.map((user) =>
          user.eligible ? (
            <>
              <li className="shadow-lg bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center p-10 rounded-lg row-span-3 col-span-1">
                {user.name}
              <img src={user.pic} />
              </li>
              <li className="shadow-lg bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center p-10 rounded-lg row-span-2">
                {user.name}
              <img src={user.pic} />
              </li>
              <li className="shadow-lg bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center p-10 rounded-lg">
                {user.name}
              <img src={user.pic} />
              </li>
            </>
          ) : (
            ''
          )
        )}
      </ul>
```

With the above code three grids are created for a single user, and total 9 grids are created instead of 3. I could not wrap my head around to find a solution. I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint.
I am trying to achieve a grid exactly like this
[The grid in my mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa2Yw.png)

Comment: So you want every user to have one `grid`? according to the image, John should be in `1` and David should be in `2` etc?

Comment: Yeah @Dhaifallah

Comment: ok so just to make sure, the final result should be like this have a look [HERE] (https://play.tailwindcss.com/SHgmQCDeqt)

Comment: Yeah, exactly! This is what I'm looking for. But when I try to map items into the grid, it does not work as expected. That's where the problem is. Thanks for putting your effort so far @Dhaifallah

Comment: Should I expect any updates? @Dhaifallah

Comment: Hey, Luck sorry about the late reply, I was struggling not gonna lie :), but I think I figured something out, I'll post my answer in a minute.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a bunch man. I sat the whole day to find an answer, but no luck. Looking forward to your answer :) @Dhaifallah

Comment: No worries dude, but don't look forward too much, I'm still learning lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this but here is my try :

**`APP.js`**

```
import React from "react";
import TestS from "./components/TestS";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="relative w-full  ">
      <TestS />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**`TestS.jsx`**

> Read the comments if there is something not clear

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function TestS() {
  // this variable will be used inside (map) later to decide which style will be rendered
  let [count] = useState(0);
  const users = [
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 23,
      pic: "https://picsum.photos/200",
      eligible: true
    },
    {
      name: "Marie",
      age: 6,
      pic: "https://picsum.photos/200",
      eligible: false
    },
    {
      name: "David",
      age: 30,
      pic: "https://picsum.photos/200",
      eligible: true
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      age: 20,
      pic: "https://picsum.photos/200",
      eligible: true
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="  ">
      <ul className="grid grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-4 mt-4 px-10">
        {users.map((user, id) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          if (user.eligible) {
            // Once there is an object passed the (if) statment the count will increase by 1 first
            count = count + 1;
            return (
              // Now it's clear that the returned element with the desired values
              // will be rendered with the classes that you specify
              count === 1 ? (
                <li
                  key={id}
                  className="shadow-lg bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center p-10 rounded-lg row-span-3 col-span-1"
                >
                  {user.name}
                  <img
                    alt="person pic"
                    src={user.pic}
                    className="w-24 h-24 object-fill"
                  />
                </li>
              ) : count === 2 ? (
                <li
                  key={id}
                  className="shadow-lg bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center p-10 rounded-lg"
                >
                  {user.name}
                  <img
                    alt="person pic"
                    src={user.pic}
                    className="w-24 h-24 object-fill"
                  />
                </li>
              ) : count === 3 ? (
                <li
                  key={id}
                  className="shadow-lg bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center p-10 rounded-lg row-span-2"
                >
                  {user.name}
                  <img
                    alt="person pic"
                    src={user.pic}
                    className="w-24 h-24 object-fill"
                  />
                </li>
              ) : (
                <h1>somthing wentt wrong</h1>
              )
            );
          }
          // eslint-disable-next-line
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestS;
```

See it [**LIVE**](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-resonance-qhfbx1?file=/src/components/TestS.jsx) on codesandbox

Comment: Dude, this is remarkable! I don't know how to thank you. I will try this out in some time and will update you. Once again thanks for taking time to solve this

Comment: No need dude, glad i could help, yes please tell me if something went wrong, btw there is another way to do this without the `count` if you are working with this exact object, but I thought  this is better.